# How to know Present view of UINavigation controller iPhoneSDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

i have one navigation controller, by using that i am pushing my view

here my problem is how to know that which view is presently appearing on my navigation controller

can any one of you give me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to look at the *topViewController* property of your *UINavigationController* (or perhaps its *visibleViewController* if you are using modal views). The current view would then be referenced by the *view* property of the returned controller.